# How do you pass use a variable for class in isKindOfClass?

Tags: objective-c

What if I want the type of class to check for to be set at runtime, and I want to pass it in from a method, how would I do that? would this work?

```
-(int)findObjectOfTypeClass:(id)classType container:(SPSprite*)sp
{

    for (int i=0; i<sp.numChildren; i++) {

        if([[sp childAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[classType class]])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

How would that method be called? like this?

```
[self findObjectOfTypeClass:NSObject container: mySprite];
```

?

I want to check through a mutableArray (mySprite) to see if there are any objects of a particular type. So I don't want to pass in an actual object, I want to pass in the type of class, so NSObject, SPSprite, etc and then use isKindOfClass to see if there's an object of that class type in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining the method as you have, you could call it like you say:

```
[self findObjectOfTypeClass:NSObject container: mySprite];
```

Though it's a bit weird to pass `NSObject` itself and it's a bit of an abuse to pass the class definition as an `id`. You can also call it as (and it's more honest to):

```
[self findObjectOfTypeClass:anInstance container: mySprite];
```

Where `anInstance` is the class of object you want to test against. But now the method name is misleading. You're probably better off implementing it as:

```
-(int)findObjectOfTypeClass:(Class)classType container:(SPSprite*)sp
{

    for (int i=0; i<sp.numChildren; i++) {

        if([[sp childAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:classType])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

And then calling it as:

```
 [self findObjectOfTypeClass:[NSObject class] container: mySprite];
```

Because its much more accurate to the description and clearer to read.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the *class* method, this way:

```
[self findObjectOfTypeClass: [NSObject class] container: mySprite];
```

As for the signature this one would be correct:

```
-(int)findObjectOfTypeClass:(Class)classType container:(SPSprite*)sp;
```

Comment: Ah ok, so is this line correct then -(int)findObjectOfTypeClass:(id)classType container:(SPSprite*)sp ? should that "id" be there? when I tried "class" it gave me an error.

Comment: It should be class, not id. Added it to the answer.

Comment: A class actually is an object. It's not incorrect to store a class in a variable of type `id` — it's just a little confusing if you specifically expect a class. That's probably why the downvote.

Comment: The fact that it is an opaque struct tricked me, but it has the same fields of a common object so this makes sense.